# Django - Cannot locate images through '/media/'

Tags: python, django

I cannot seem to get images to work on my django project.

I have created a "profile" model that is 1:1 with each user, and one of the profile fields is a profile picture.

---

I have added the following to my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I have added the following to my project urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
```

and the following after all my urlpatterns:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The image is saved in my root directory/media/profile_pics

---

When I open the missing image in a new tab, I get a 404 error saying that no image could be found at, "http://localhost:8000/profile/profile_pics/ProfilePic.jpg"

---

However, when I change

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

to

```
MEDIA_URL = '/profile/'
```

the picture WILL load on my profile page, profile.html page with the 'profile/' url path, but the picture will not load on any other page.

---

What am I missing?

Comment: How do you *render* the URL in the template?

Comment: I'm still learning, so I don't know if this answers your question:  In my users/views.py I have a "profile" view that includes `return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)` to render the profile template.  To access this, I have `path('', include('users.urls'))` included in my project's "urlpatterns" and `path('profile/', views.profile, name='Profile')` in my users/urls.py

Comment: oh, unless this is what you meant:  My image tag in the profile template, where I'm trying to load the image, looks like this: `<img src="{{ user.profile.image }}" class="profile-pic-onprofile">`

Comment: OH!  I didn't have ".url" on the source.  It seems to be working now!